# Add a hyperlink to a list item pointing to a folder that is NOT on a server (Shared folder)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, folder, hyperlink

I have modified my list to the point where I can now add hyperlinks to it, but it does not appear that I can simply add my link to the `hyperlink field` as I had thought.

I attempt to enter the address and a test string of text however unless it is a web address it give me the error

> "The address is not valid. To fix this problem, enter an address that can be accessed from any location."
>
> I have tried using both forward and back slashes in the address line in the hopes that that would help - it didn't. It gives the same error when trying to add a link to my desktop as well.

I am using Sharepoint through Internet Explorer and I believe it is the 2010 version.

[image: This is the problem]

I also read through this but it didn't help terribly much as it appears that the user did not have the same error I am receiving:
[File:// hyperlink to a shared drive](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134836/file-hyperlink-to-a-shared-drive)

I'm quite unfamiliar with SharePoint so perhaps this is not the best way to go about doing this, but the end goal is to have on SharePoint a list of links to our finished optimization runs (stored on our shared folder) that can be sorted and filtered by their different parameters. Initially the attempt was to "attach" a shortcut file but that just resulted in it pulling the actual file which would have added up to a large amount (too large) of data being on SharePoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `K:/` try `file://K:/`

Or even better, find out the real address of the fileshare that you've got mapped to the drive letter K. When you go to your Computer and you see the K drive listed under Network Locations, does it have a name like `Something (\\contoso.com) (K:)`? If it was named using the default values when mapping a drive, that would mean its file location is `file://contoso.com/Something`

Using the drive letter on its own may work depending on your patch level (it works in my environment) but it's dependent on every user having that drive letter mapped to the appropriate fileshare location on each of their devices. That's why using the actual file share name is preferable.

Comment: the "file://" is what I was missing! Thank you so much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `file://` protocol handler, e.g.:

`file://fileServerName/shareName`

This does work in SharePoint 2010. You will not be able to use drive letters.

Comment: when you say fileServerName what does that mean? Same question for the "shareName" part. I've only spent about 2 hours total in Sharepoint...

Comment: When you map the "K:" drive, as in your example, you map it to "\\fileServerName\shareName". You need this information (transposed to using forward slashes). If you don't have this information, you can either talk to your system administrator(s)/helpdesk, or from your client machine, go to Start -> Run, type in `cmd`. In the Command Prompt, type in `net use`. Here you will see "K:" mapped to a path (that "\\fileServerName\shareName"). This is what you need to type in the file://fileServerName/sharename for your URL in the List Item.