# Links to network drives do not work for some users

Tags: sharepoint-online

In Sharepoint Online, on Enterprise Wiki pages, I have some links that point to
network drives on the company network, like this:

```
<a href="file://servername/file.xlsx">File link</a>
```

where servername is the name of a server on the network.

For one user, the link does not work. Nothing happens when he clicks on it in  Edge, Firefox or Chrome browsers.

When I put the same link on a basic page on our company web server (outside Sharepoint, but on the company network), it works.

I have found out that Chrome and Firefox block 'file:' links by default.

Since only one user has reported the problem, I wonder if it is a trust issue for Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the Sharepoint URL was not a Trusted site under Internet Explorer -> Options -> Security.

After adding the site URL, the links work normally.

Answer (score 0):

> I opened an MS case and they confirmed it will not work in SPO. Here's
>   their reply:
>
> "\servername\folder will not work in SharePoint online. Shared Drive
>   in your network is the Shared resources in your domain network.
>
> In SharePoint online you can only add the link with fully qualified
>   domain. When you add the shared network drive like \servername\folder
>   as link to SharePoint online, it consider it folder hosted on its own
>   web server. When you click on the link SharePoint add prefix
>   domain.sharepoint.com\servername\folder to make it FQDN. This sends
>   the query to own WFE. This is by design."

For more information and work arounds, please check the below links,

1. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/links-to-shared-drive-not-working/7a5e714e-3688-4815-97b1-f7ee2e4ae5db
2. [File:// hyperlink to a shared drive](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134836/file-hyperlink-to-a-shared-drive)
3. https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Link-Shared-Drive.htm

[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/shared-drive-links-not-working-in-ie/5d987904-f595-4c30-8f82-1be3fe8da743)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following article to add hyperlink to network drive:

https://kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Link-Shared-Drive.htm

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/056d36fa-3e4f-4016-a74a-9200c13b1e36/adding-hyperlink-to-network-drive?forum=sharepointgeneral