# Access network file share as http URL from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, hyperlink, network-drive

I have a network file share and i want to hyperlink to the network file share using http protocol.

For example:

Network file share: **\asgfgrexe\Network\marketing**

http URL to hyperlink : **http://asgfgrexe/Network/marketing**

Is it possible to access the network file share like a http url?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134836/file-hyperlink-to-a-shared-drive

Comment: I agree with Trevor, it is not supported to access network file share as http URL from SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

No, because file shares use their own protocol (`file://` is just one example). You would need a service that ran on top of the file share which provided the `http://` protocol.